# How much memory does as.data.table use?

Tags: r, data.table

If `x` is a data frame, how much extra memory is need to perform the following operations?

```
y <- as.data.table(x)    #1

x <- as.data.table(x)    #2
```

Comment: You can use `mem_used`, `mem_change` from `pryr`

Comment: @akrun Thanks, I thought `as.data.table` does `setDT` when I use #2

Comment: the `set` functions are very efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mem_used`, `mem_change` functions from `pryr` can be used.

```
 library(pryr)
 df1 <- data.frame(v1 = 1:1e6, v2 = rnorm(1e6))
 mem_used()
 #38.8 MB


 mem_change(dt <- as.data.table(df1))
 #12.1 MB <---

 mem_change(setDT(df1))
 #94.1 kB  <---
```

Comment: I got 12.1 MB in a new console, instead of 6.42 kB

Comment: @user3226167  I am using `data.table1.10.0`.  Now, I am getting 12.1 MB, may be the session earlier was having other objects.  Also, using `setDT`, it is in `kB`

Comment: I also find that omitting the line `mem_used()` modifies the result

Comment: @user3226167  It would be the change from previous memory used

Answer (score 0):

After loading these data and table, you can use memory.size() to check you memory, also you can change your sys memory by memory.limit() if need.